# Problems trying to load hwi service in hive-1.1.0?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been teaching myself to use Hadoop (2.6.0) and associated applications in the case hive-1.1.0. I am run the hwi server using the information on Hadoop for Dummies page 237, but following the instructions there, I keep running into an error message  which says the WAR file is not found in hive-1.1.0/lib.

I had to configure `$HIVE_HOME/config/hive-site.xml` file to point at where this WAR file is in `hive-1.1.0/lib` but when i run the command to start the hwi server, it does start but then breaks because in running this command, some of the lines in the path (which should come from my definition in hive-site.xml) are duplicated so the command cannot find the WAR file. I am attaching a screenshot of my hive-site.xml file and the results from what happens when I run the command `hive --service hwi`.

Relevant part of `$HIVE_HOME/config/hive-site.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
  <configuration>
     <!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->
    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop/Hive/warehouse</value>
      <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hive.hwi.war.file></name>
      <value>$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-hwi.0.12.0.war</value>
      <description> This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
    </property>  
  </configuration>
```

On this version of Hive, there was no WAR file, and I copied the `hive-hwi.0.12.0.war` from hive-0.12.0 as suggested

Results from the following:

```
[hadoop@fedora21_2 ~]$ hive --service hwi
15/04/05 15:53:02 INFO hwi.HWIServer: HWI is starting up
15/04/05 15:53:04 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.hwi.war.file> does not exist
15/04/05 15:53:04 FATAL hwi.HWIServer: HWI WAR file not found at /home/hadoop/hive-1.1.0/home/hadoop/hive-1.1.0/lib/hive-hwi-0.12.0.war
[hadoop@fedora21_2 ~]$
```

It looks as if when I ran the command to load the HWI service, somehow the command botched up the path to the WAR file as posted in hive-site.xml. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

change this property from:

```
<property>
            <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
            <value>{$HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-[version].war</value>
</property>
```

to:

```
<property>
            <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
            <value>/lib/hive-hwi-[version].war</value>
</property>
```

You were having the problem because the final execution path became {$HIVE_HOME}/{$HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-[version].war

This happened because you are already at the {$HIVE_HOME} directory while reading the configuration file.

So, if you remove {$HIVE_HOME} from your configuration, you get {$HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-[version].war which is the correct path.

in your case, [version] = 0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

make a folder inside hive

```
home/hadoop/hive-1.1.0/lib
```

and paste all the files of lib in this, then run the command

```
hive --service hwi
```

that will work will the time bug is fixed.